# How to satisfy trait bounds for `impl futures::Future: futures::TryStream`

Tags: rust

I have a HTTP api that uses pagination, and I want to wrap it into a general Rust stream so that the same interface can be used for all endpoints, and so that I can use the trait functions that come with the `Stream` trait.

I'm getting this error that I do not quite understand:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `try_collect` found for opaque type `impl futures::Future` in the current scope
   --> src/lib.rs:316:69
    |
316 |         let result: Result<Vec<Vec<NotificationEvent>>, _> = stream.try_collect().await;
    |                                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `impl futures::Future`
    |
    = note: the method `try_collect` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
            `impl futures::Future: futures::TryStream`
            which is required by `impl futures::Future: futures::TryStreamExt`
            `&impl futures::Future: futures::TryStream`
            which is required by `&impl futures::Future: futures::TryStreamExt`
            `&mut impl futures::Future: futures::TryStream`
            which is required by `&mut impl futures::Future: futures::TryStreamExt`
```

This is my implementation:

```rust
    pub async fn v1_events_get_st(
        &self,
        params: &Option<GetEvents>,
    ) -> impl TryStream<Item = Result<Vec<NotificationEvent>, UniErr>> + '_ {

        let x = stream::try_unfold((true, (*params).clone()), move |state: (bool, Option<GetEvents>)| async move {
            let (remaining, mut thisParams) = state;

            if !remaining {
                return Ok(None);
            }

            return match self.v1_events_get(&thisParams).await {
                Ok(res) => {

                    if let Some(ref mut p) = thisParams {
                        if let Some((_, last)) = res.get_from_to() {
                            p.set_after(last);
                        }
                    }

                    Ok(Some((res.data, (res.remaining, thisParams))))
                },
                Err(err) => Err(err),
            }
        });
        return x;

    }
```

```rust
        let stream = c.v1_events_get_st(&p);
        let result: Result<Vec<Vec<NotificationEvent>>, _> = stream.try_collect().await;
```

These are the bounds on `try_collect`:

```rust
    fn try_collect<C: Default + Extend<Self::Ok>>(self) -> TryCollect<Self, C>
    where
        Self: Sized,
    {
        assert_future::<Result<C, Self::Error>, _>(TryCollect::new(self))
    }
```

Why would I need to implement Default and Extend?

I cannot easily implement Default as it cannot be derived with structs with enums, I have a lot of enums.

And as for extend, wouldn't the `Vec` already have this?

Question: Is there a way to get a more detailed error on the exact trait bounds that are not satisfied?

Question: Is there a better way to wrap this into a Stream or other common interface? I'm starting to think it may be better just to use a for loop and not implement the `Stream` trait.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `async fn`, it automatically wraps the return value in a future, hence the error about `impl futures::Future`. Just remove the `async` keyword and it should work.